# TypeScript/Eslint throwing a 'Promise returned' error on a Express Router async route

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, typeorm, express-router

I have the following endpoint setup to reset a database after test runs:

```
import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

const resetDatabase = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const connection = getConnection();
  await connection.dropDatabase();
  await connection.synchronize();
};

// typescript-eslint throws an error in the following route:
router.post('/reset', async (_request, response) => {
  await resetTestDatabase();
  response.status(204).end();
});

export default router;
```

The entire route since `async` is underlined with a typescript-eslint error `Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected.`

The app works perfectly but I'm not sure if I should be doing a safer implementation or just ignoring/disabling Eslint for this one. Any idea of what's wrong with that code?

Comment: I put this into the Typescript playground and it compiles without any errors so I don't think anything is wrong with the code. Maybe if you share your linting configuration we can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Actually scratch that, I've checked what linting rule causes this and I'll write a proper answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are using the [no-misused-promises](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md) rule which states that you cannot return `Promise<void>` in a place where `void` is expected.

This means that you cannot return `Promise<void>` from your Express handler because the return type of `RequestHandler` from the library specifies that the return type should be `void`. I would suggest that you change it to return `Promise<Response>` by adding a simple `return` keyword:

```
import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

const resetDatabase = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const connection = getConnection();
  await connection.dropDatabase();
  await connection.synchronize();
};

// typescript-eslint throws an error in the following route:
router.post('/reset', async (_request, response) => {
  await resetTestDatabase();
  return response.status(204).send();  // <----- return added here
});

export default router;
```

The other option would be to avoid using `async/await`:

```
router.post('/reset', (_request, response) => {
  resetDatabase().then(() => response.status(204).send());
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The second solution works, but adding the return to the first one keeps throwing the error, it really feels like eslint does not like that async. The rule is indeed `no-misused-promises`, forgot to mention it. Any idea of what might be happening with async await? I'm actually trying to get rid of .then()s for consistency =)

Comment: When you add `async` to a function, it automatically makes the return type a `Promise`. If you were to return nothing as you do in your `async` function, the return type is `Promise<void>` instead of just `void`. Honestly, I'm not sure that linting rule is worth it so I would be tempted to disable it.

Comment: Maybe you can try adding a type annotation to your handler. Like `async (_request, response): Promise<express.Response> => {`

Comment: His majesty doesn't like it. There is only so much time one can spend trying to appease Typescripot :P I'll just leave the then(), thanks again mate!

Comment: Is there any way to solve this without then()?

Comment: A lot of places like event handlers, I'm just trying to use `await` inside the callback function, I couldn't care less about whether it returns nothing or a promise of nothing, it makes no difference. It's ugly, hard to read, and a pain in the ass to have to use some verbose inner async autocalled function every time you want to use an await. No thanks. To disable the rule in this specific scenario you can set the `checksVoidReturn` option for `@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises` to `false`.

Comment: It does make a difference, because a Promise can fail so you could end up with an unhandled promise rejection. If you know that this can't happen in your particular scenario, then you can silence the warning in that particular place (or disable checksVoidReturn entirely as you suggested)

Answer (score 17):

I found a solution that doesn't involves using `then()` and let you use the abstraction of async without getting cursed by the eslint, there's two solutions *(but i recommend more the second one)*

##### First Solution: Using "inside async"

This is basic using a async inside the void like this:

```ts
router.post('/reset', (_request, response) => {
    (async () => {
        await resetTestDatabase();
        response.status(204).end();
    })()
});
```

##### Second Solution *(recommended)*: "Type Overlap"

The second option is to you use it as an async, as Always, but say "hey TypeScript, nothing is wrong here hehe" with the "as" keyword

```ts
import { RequestHandler } from 'express'

router.post('/reset', (async (_request, response) => {
    await resetTestDatabase();
    response.status(204).end();
}) as RequestHandler);
```

Comment: What's the benefit of doing this? It sounds like OP gets a linting error for something that's desired behavior. Rather than create a complicated workaround for the linting error, it makes way more sense to disable the rule... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, sometimes to disable some rules is kinda mean when you're using eslint, because if you don't want rules, why you using eslint after all? 

Comment: I think that's a great question! Why use eslint at all? To me it's to enforce certain rules around code that ensure that the code is better. If applying a rule makes code worse, it's not a good rule.

Comment: Fair enough, make sense

Comment: You use eslint, because this is a very valid error that in some cases causes terribly hard to find bugs. It's just that this is not such a case, that's why you ignore it *just* here, not for all the code.

Answer (score 10):

After also going around the houses a little, here is an update:

Express 5 now handles this correctly. Confirmation [here from the Express maintainers](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4892#issuecomment-1101366213):

Typings however are not yet (at the time of writing) updated/available for Express 5 so the error still displays, despite being resolved. Follow [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/50871) on the DefinitelyTyped repo for conversation on updates.

In the meantime, as suggested already by [KuryKat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69860515/16019434), handling with the `RequestHandler` should be safe in Express 5.

```
import { RequestHandler } from 'express'

router.post('/reset', (async (_request, response) => {
    await resetTestDatabase();
    response.status(204).end();
}) as RequestHandler);
```

In Express 4 however, better to handle the error either with an explicit `.catch(...)`:

```
app.get("/manifest.webmanifest", (_req, res) => {
  getManifest(pwaOptions)
    .then(result => res.send(result))
    .catch(error => res.status(500).send('Unexpected error'))
});
```

Or use an async handler:

[express-async-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler)

[express-async-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-router)

See [discussion here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/49677#issuecomment-734158696) regarding Express 4 for reference.

Comment: I think for the time being where ExpressJS5 is still in beta the express-async-handler is the "cleanest" solution. As you don't need to alter or duplicate any logic and just need to wrap the router callable in that function.